# Paste Excel range to Outlook email body with custom format

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, format

I'm developing a macro to paste a range (from Excel) into an Outlook email.  I'm using the "Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)".  It works and pastes the range into the email with one exception.

The range has a custom format and I would like to carry that format to the body of the email.

This is the custom format:

> `(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)`

This seems to be the applicable section of the function but I'm not sure how to incorporate the custom format in this code.

```
With TempWB.Sheets(1)

        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0

    End With
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for taking the time to look at this.........

Comment: RangeToHtml uses Excel's PublishObjects to convert the range to an Html document. That document is full of poor quality CSS. Does PublishObjects not process this format correctly?  Finding a number that has not been formatted to your requirement within the Html document would be a nightmare. I believe it would be easier to create your own RangeToHtml function. This answer of mine may give you some ideas: [VBA Excel to Outlook font formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48896589/973283)

Comment: @TonyDallimore.....Thanks for the reply.  The custom formatting is only red and green on an arrow that is up or down depending whether the value in the last column is a positive or negative number.  I was hoping for something quick and easy.  If it's not the end users are going to have to do without the arrows.  This is really a nice to have and not something that I'm going to spend a great deal of time on.  thanks for your help......

Comment: @Shaves  I do not understand. If the custom format you specify was used as a `NumberFormat` it would give different appearances for a numeric value depending on the value being postive, negative, zero or non-numeric. Such a format can be used to change the colour but you do not use this functionality. To change the colour of an arrow depending on the value of a different cell would require use of conditional formatting. My understanding is that PublishObjects handles conditional formatting.

Comment: @TonyDallimore............Thanks for the info.  I hadn't even considered conditional formatting.  I looked at the original document a little further and the red / green arrows are a result of conditional formatting.  I'll research some more and see if I can get the conditional formatting to carry over to the body of the e-mail.  Thanks again........